# Show by comparison with an appropriate geometric series that, $e^x-1<\left(\frac{2x}{2-x}\right)$ for 0<x<2.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Show by comparison with an appropriate geometric series that,

$e^x-1<\left(\dfrac{2x}{2-x}\right)$ for $0\lt x\lt2$.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$\frac{2x}{2-x}=\frac{2x}{2(1-\frac{x}{2})} = \frac{x}{1-\frac{x}{2}}=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty x(\frac{x}{2})^n$

This follows from the identity $\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty a r^n = \frac{a}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$. Here, $a=x$ and $r=\frac{x}{2}$.

$e^{x} -1 = \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Rewriting those series so that they start at the same index, you should be able to show the desired result.

Comment: Are you using the sum of an infinite geometric sequence formula to show: $\frac{x}{1-\frac{x}{2}}=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty x(\frac{x}{2})^n$ of so, can you explain that a bit?

Comment: Is that enough to clear it up?

Comment: yup thanks that works!